# AWS Billing : will i be charge if i only stop the instance not terminate it?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a query , that i have an`EC2` instance which i need to use for running some tests but i do not need it to be up for 24x7 (only on office hours i need it to be running),

As one potential solution i am planning to stop the `EC2` instance and then relaunch it

If i **stop** the instance (**not terminate it** ).
Will i still be eligible for billing ?

Comment: http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/FAQs/FAQ_0149_-_What%27s_the_difference_between_Terminating_and_Stopping_an_EC2_Instance%3F#Stop_Instance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question best posed to AWS support.

Comment: ok if u think that way, and by all the downvoting i understand the same ... i will delete the question by myself ! @fuero

Comment: If people thinks this is off topic. No it's not!!!!!!! some future developers helps this kind of thread. LIKE ME!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your instance is stopped, you are only charged for its associated storage (e.g. your personal AMIs or EBS volumes), but not the hourly compute charge. The hourly compute charge applies only when the instance is running.